# Wine collapsed input fields

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, wine, playonlinux

### HI!

I installed **playonlinux** on my *xubuntu x64 16.04 PC (with nvidia driver 384.111)*. I followed the instructions for installing *Photoshop CS6*.

When i was started the application, the fonts were weird and the inputs are unusable. Did I something wrong?

I include a screen-shot: [xfce-ps-window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxRs9.png)

I also tried with Xorg driver (nothing changed).
I think it isn't a driver related issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which instructions/steps do you follow? Windows software not always work flawless with wine. Consider trying [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org).

Comment: I followed the instructions of playonlinux Photoshop CS6 installation. Gimp is good but not for web designing.

Answer (score 0):

### I found the solution!

I installed the latest wine version, with the latest winetricks.
I installed these libraries with winetricks: vcrun2008 vcrun2010 vcrun2012 vcrun2013 atmlib msxml3 msxml6 gdiplus allfonts
as this page suggested : https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=34741

So playonlinux is wrong. Now I have a bit issue with the viewport. I have to click on it to update. ( a bit annoying but ok)